# How to use 'dh_installgsettings'?

Tags: application-development, packaging, gsettings

My app use systay.
I know I should use gsettings to set the 'systray-whitelist' key.

Now I would like to package my app.
After I googled, I guess dh_installgsettings can help me.

So I put a file named 'myapp.gsettings-override' and put the following content:

```
com.canonical.Unity.Panel]
systay-whitelist=['myapp']
```

1. Am I right?
2. Will 'myapp' be appended to systray-whitelist?

Answer (score 1):

You've got part of it right.  This is what you need to do in order to modify a setting like you want to.

1) Add override_dh_installgsettings to debian/rules:

```
override_dh_installgsettings:
dh_installgsettings --priority=50
```

2) Add the gsettings-override file like you did.

Now the bad news.  Your change will not append to the whitelist, it will overwrite it.  In addition, if the user has modified the setting in any way at any time, their modifications will always take precedence.